# Axios GET request sent after axios stream.on("data") not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a backend API that has a `/subscribe` endpoint which returns a `stream` of data.

I also have a node process & I am using [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) to send a request to my backend API with a response type of `"stream"`, which works fine, but the problem is that in the callback passed to the  `stream.on("data")`, I need to do another `axios` call but that call/promise never resolves.
My code looks like this

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const getTasks = async () => {
  const { data: stream } = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/agent/runners/1/subscribe`, {
    responseType: 'stream',
  });

  stream.on('data', async (data) => {
    console.log('received data');

    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/agent/runners/1/tarball-download-url`,
    );

    console.log('response ', response);
  });
};

getTasks();
```

In this code above, the first **console.log** works & keeps logging `received data` to the console multiple times, as expected, but the second **console.log** is never reached & nothing ever gets logged to the console.

Also, if i hit the url passed to the `axios` call in the callback in my browser, i get the response.

I can also verify that my server is being hit by the `axios.get` in the callback, but I am not sure why i never get any response in the node process

Comment: Ok my best guess is that your scripts terminates before the result from axios is back or it throws an error because the URL is returning a error. I just tries your code with just some random URL and it worked just fine.

Comment: Try adding `try...catch` to see if it is failing due to some reason.

Comment: You have ZERO error handling in this code.  Start by catching ALL possible errors and perhaps it will show you what's happening.  You need error handling for each `await` and on the stream itself.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, **there is nothing wrong with my JS code in this question**.

The problem was with my server. I am using laravel & the php server for my backend & it was handling only one request at a time, so the request to `/subscribe` which has a stream response - which means its a never ending request was blocking all other requests.

I ended up using [laravel octane](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/octane#main-content) which solved my problem